# List comprehension with if statement for a list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am learning about list comprehension, and trying to solve an exercise but I am stuck with the right index and arguments.
So I have this list of dictionary called 'people', and I need to create a function with 2 arguments (first one, a list of dictionary, like 'people', and the other one, 'minimum_age' with default value of 18 if the argument is not specified) that needs to return a new list which includes only the people above the minimum_age. If the age value is not specified, that person shall be excluded. I would need to solve this with list comprehension.

```
       people = [{"name": "John", "age": 12}, {"name": "Sam", "age": 36}, {"name": "Frank"}
       def function(people, minimum_age=18):       
       new_list = 
       return new_list
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? See also [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to do a regular list-comprehension, but if you don't always have the age then you should put an absurdly small default age in the condition clause:

```
people = [{"name": "John", "age": 12}, {"name": "Sam", "age": 36}, {"name": "Frank"}]
def function(people, minimum_age=18):       
   new_list = [p for p in people if p.get('age', -10000) >= minimum_age] 
   return new_list 

print(function(people))
```

If you don't want to assume a specific "minimal" age then you can use `numpy` and have the default value set to `-np.inf`.

Note, that the list-comprehension is just short-hand for an explicit loop, which would look like this:

```
people = [{"name": "John", "age": 12}, {"name": "Sam", "age": 36}, {"name": "Frank"}]
def function(people, minimum_age=18): 
    new_list = []
    for p in people:
        if p.get('age', -10000) >= minimum_age:
            new_list.append(p)
    return new_list
      
print(function(people))
```

Comment: Why not just use `-1`? A person's age has to be a natural number, so using any negative number would work just fine. But FWIW, you don't need NumPy for `-inf`, you can just use `float('-inf')`.

Comment: Because I don't want to assume that the data is sensible. Maybe the function should be raising "absurd" cases as well...So any minimum_age should be a valid input with the expected output.

Comment: I'm not following. Are you familiar with "[garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)"? If the input is not sensible, the function can't be expected to work properly, so if you want to handle that case, it should raise an error.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of the question at hand. The data format might have "negative" ages for multiple reasons, and I don't think assuming that ages are positive should be a part of the asnwer.